# Adding an insert picture ( from site column ) SP 2010 - becomes broken with lots of added url encoding?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I added an "insert image" column to a form via "site columns".
It seems to work well until I view the image that was "browsed" and selected via the "Edit Image Dialog Box".

The picture comes up as a broken link and the URL is chock full of URL encoded letters. What am I doing wrong?